# Finding a recursion

Tags: sequences-and-series, recursion

I am supposed to find a recursion for the following sequence:
$$a_{n} = (1+\sqrt{s})^{n} + (1-\sqrt{s})^{n}$$
where $s \in \mathbb{N}$ fixed.
I tried playing around with it using the binomial theorem, however, I was not able to find a solution!
I'd greatly appreciate help/hints/solutions!
Thanks in advance

Comment: Start by finding one for the sequence $(1+\sqrt{s})^n$, and another one for $(1-\sqrt{s})^n$. Then try to find one (hint: second order) satisfied by both.

Comment: $$a_{n+1}= c_1 a_{n}+c_2 a_{n-1}\\t^2-c_1 t-c2 =0 \\a_{n}=c_1' t_1^n +c_2' t_2^n$$when $t_1 ,t_2 $are roots of  $\space t^2-c_1 t-c2 =0$ so now $t_1=1-\sqrt{s} ,t_2=1+\sqrt{s} $

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\begin{align}a_{n+2}&=(1+\sqrt s)^{n+2}+(1-\sqrt s)^{n+2}\\&=(1+\sqrt s)^n(1+\sqrt s)^2+(1-\sqrt s)^n(1-\sqrt s)^2\\&=(1+\sqrt s)^n(1+2\sqrt s+s)+(1-\sqrt s)^n(1-2\sqrt s+s)\\&=(1+\sqrt s)^n(2(1+\sqrt s)+s-1)+(1-\sqrt s)^n(2(1-\sqrt s)+s-1)\\&=2(1+\sqrt s)^{n+1}+(s-1)(1+\sqrt s)^{n}+2(1-\sqrt s)^{n+1}+(s-1)(1-\sqrt s)^n\\&=2a_{n+1}+(s-1)a_{n}\end{align}$$

Answer (score 1):

Lemma: if $a_{n}=Ax^n+By^n$,then we have
$$a_{n+2}=(x+y)a_{n+1}-xya_{n}$$
It is clear

Answer (score 1):

$a_n$ is the trace of the matrix $M^n$, where $M$ is the companion matrix of the polynomial:
$$ p(t) = (t-1-\sqrt{s})(t-1+\sqrt{s}) = t^2-2t+(1-s)\tag{1}$$
hence the Cayley-Hamilton theorem applied to:
$$ a_n = \text{Tr}\left(\begin{array}{cc}0 & s-1\\ 1 & 2 \end{array}\right)^n \tag{2}$$
gives:

> $$ a_{n+2} = 2\, a_{n+1} + (s-1)\, a_n. \tag{3} $$